# GRPD email in cookie relation

Tags: email, cookies

Our website utilizes HTTPS and our question is:

1. Are we violating GDPR consent by storing use email in cookies?

Other question:

2. It this even advised to do?

I am completely aware that cookies are not a secure way of storing sensitive data. What we are trying to accomplish is to store login information in order to help returning customers to only enter their password on the login form by storing their email data.